# Can't upload photos via the (TinyMCE) by using laravel voyager page block plugin

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce, voyager

why i can not insert photos from my computer for page block though (TinyMCE). Those, when adding a photo, nothing happens; it works only if I insert a link with a photo[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAp5M.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue create when we are using page block plugin in laravel voyager.i try & this solution is work form me

In config/voyager.php add an additional JS file
'additional_js' => [ 'js/tinymce.js', ],

Then create your tinymce.js file with the following code (adjust to your needs of course):

```js
function tinymce_init_callback(editor)
{
  editor.remove();
  editor = null;

  tinymce.init({
    menubar: false,
    selector:'textarea.richTextBox',
    skin_url: $('meta[name="assets-path"]').attr('content')+'?path=js/skins/voyager',
    min_height: 450,
    resize: 'vertical',
    plugins: 'link, image, code, table, textcolor, lists',
    extended_valid_elements : 'input[id|name|value|type|class|style|required|placeholder|autocomplete|onclick]',
    file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
      input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

      /*
        Note: In modern browsers input[type="file"] is functional without
        even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
        or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
        just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
        once you do not need it anymore.
      */

      input.onchange = function () {
        var file = this.files[0];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
          /*
            Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
            registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
            necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
          */
          var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
          var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
          var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
          var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
          blobCache.add(blobInfo);

          /* call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name */
          cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      };

      input.click();
    },
    toolbar: 'styleselect bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image table | code',
    convert_urls: false,
    image_caption: true,
    image_title: true,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

download new TinyMce Editor and write a path where you wan to save the image into below file
`tinymce\plugins\filemanager\config.php`

This solution works for me

Comment: @Maduhri Patel i have tried plugin option but this not working i am getting plugin initialization issue.

Comment: which version of tinymce you are using ?

Comment: "pvtl/voyager-frontend": "^0.8.5","pvtl/voyager-page-blocks": "^0.8.3", "tcg/voyager": "^1.1"

Comment: i am getting this problem in voyager page block plugin.

Comment: hey link may be help you https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/2365

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution but it not fit with my work. Because it reinitialize  the tinymce editor and I don't want to reinitialize it, according to the first answer from [shazim ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8539385/shazim-ali)

So I create tinymce.js file with the following code:

```
function tinymce_setup_callback(editor) {

editor.settings.content_css = "/css/custom_tiny_mce.css?" + new Date().getTime() + "",
    force_br_newlines = true;
editor.settings.image_caption = false;
}

tinyMCE.on('AddEditor', function (e) {
e.editor.settings.plugins = "link, image, code, table, textcolor, lists";
e.editor.settings.toolbar = "styleselect bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor | 
alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image table | 
code | sizeselect | fontselect |  fontsizeselect";

e.editor.settings.image_caption = false;
e.editor.settings.image_title = true;

e.editor.settings.extended_valid_elements = 'input[id|name|value|type|class|style|required|placeholder|autocomplete|onclick]';

});
```

and I added a form in the vendor's pvtl view file too.

> edit-add.blade.php

```
<iframe id="form_target" name="form_target" style="display:none"></iframe>
    <form id="my_form" action="{{ route('voyager.upload') }}" target="form_target" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:0px;height:0;overflow:hidden">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input name="image" id="upload_file" type="file" onchange="$('#my_form').submit();this.value='';">
        <input type="hidden" name="type_slug" id="type_slug" value="pages">
    </form>
```

or you can extend the view according to the [Pvtl documentation](https://github.com/pvtl/voyager-page-blocks#2-build-the-html)